# Can I append a new transformer or estimator to the pipeline?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

In Spark ML, Can I load saved pipeline and append a new transformer to this loaded pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getStages` method on the `Pipeline` object to get an `Array[PipelineStage]` then append the desired `PipelineStage` using the `:+` scala operator.

```
val pipeline = //your pipeline
val newStage = //you new stage
pipeline.getStages :+ new Stage
```

Hope it helps. Best Regards